# How can I play mp4 with vlcj?

Tags: java, eclipse, vlc, vlcj

I am trying to play an .mp4 file in my java app. I don't need any control buttons (play, stop) etc. When I run this code, the only thing I see is a black square. What can I do about it?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class Vid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Play");
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(c);
        f.setContentPane(p);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

        MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(f));
        emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));

        emp.prepareMedia("C:/file.mp4");
        emp.play();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The screen is black simply because your media did not start to play.

If you check the return value from the `prepareMedia` and/or `play` calls that you're making, you might find they return false to indicate an error.

This is probably because you have specified a Java platform-independent style of filename "c:/file.mp4".

You need to realise that vlcj uses LibVLC, a native library, and what you are therefore passing to that native library literally is "c:/file.mp4" - that is not the correct filename to use on Windows.

You need to pass "c:\file.mp4" instead, and more precisely "c:\\file.mp4" since the backslash must be escaped.

Unrelated to your problem, there is no need to call `prepareMedia` before playing, use the `playMedia` method instead.