# vlcj shows only black screen

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I solved the [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470390/how-do-i-load-the-vlcj-library). After that, I wrote the code to launch the YouTube player. However, even when the window is created, only the black screen is displayed and there is no sound. I use Java 8 64-bit, vlcj-4.4.1, vlcj-natives-4.1.0, jna-5.2.0, jna-platform-5.2.0 versions. Also, vlc is installed in the path "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC". How can I solve it?

```
public class Video {

    private static final int width = 880, height = 495; //frame.setBounds(0, 200, width, height + 37);
    private final JFrame frame;
    private final CallbackMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public Video(String url) {
        frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setBounds(0, 200, width, height + 37);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayerComponent = new CallbackMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018470/how-can-i-play-mp4-with-vlcj

Comment: The mp4 in the folder will play, but the videos on YouTube will not play.